# Why is this returned array not working?

Tags: java, arrays, return

In this code I'm trying to pass a two dimensional array of chars into cArray and return a one dimensional array of elements that display a string of each row of the two dimensional array.

Example:

Input array (two dimensonal):

> 'a' 'b' 'c' 'd'
>
> 'e' 'f' 'g' 'h'
>
> 'i' 'j' 'k' 'l'

Returned array (one dimensional):

> abcd
>
> efgh
>
> ijkl

Here is my code:

Main:

```
public class hw2p1
{   
   public static void main (String [] args) 
   {

  // declare and initialize array of chars
  char[][] array = { {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'},
                     {'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'},
                     {'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'} };

  cArray array1 = new cArray(array); 

  String[] array2 = array1.getArray();

  for (int i=0; i<array2.length; i++) 
    System.out.println(i+" "+array2[i]);


  }
}
```

cArray:

```
public class cArray
{   

   private String[] newArray;

   public cArray ( char[][] array2 )
   {  
      String[] newArray = new String[array2.length];

      for (int i=0; i < array2.length; i++)
         newArray[i] = String.valueOf(array2[i]);

      for (int l=0; l < array2.length; l++)
         System.out.println(newArray[l]);



   }
   public String[] getArray()
   {
      return newArray;
   }
}
```

I get this error when I try to run this:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   hw2p1.main(hw2p1.java:16)

Sorry if this is an obvious error. I'm very new to programming. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
String[] newArray = new String[array2.length];
```

That's declaring a *local* variable in the constructor - so you're not assigning a value to the *field* at all. You just want:

```
newArray = new String[array2.length];
```

Having said that, it's not clear why you need to create an instance for this at all - I'd be tempted to just have a single method with a signature of:

```
static String[] combineArrays(char[][] arrays)
```

Then you *can* use just a local variable, and there'll be no field to worry about at all. This could be in the same class as your `main` method, too.

Comment: I like your explanation and the suggestion to not make `cArray` a class at all but use a function.  Just adding that writing `this.newArray` makes it even more clear that we are using the instance variable.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed everything and I ended up just doing what you suggested by putting it as a single method instead of a whole new class.

Answer (score 2):

Your local variable `newArray` is hiding the field `newArray`. Change this line:

```
String[] newArray = new String[array2.length];
```

to this:

```
newArray = new String[array2.length];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `cArray` method, you are actually initializing a new local variable. Instead, you should use the instance variable.

Replace this:

```
String[] newArray = new String[array2.length];
```

with

```
newArray = new String[array2.length];
```

Also, it's always nice to do a `null` check:

```
if(array2!=null){
}
```